# Missing space key in frametitle of beamer

Tags: beamer, frame-title

Why is there a space ' ' missing in the title, although I wrote `\frametitle{\insertsection - \insertsubsection}` with the equivalent space.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Boadilla}

\begin{document}

    \section{Section}
    
    \subsection{Subsection}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{\insertsection - \insertsubsection}
        Frame
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: missing space in frametitle of beamer]

Comment: The space is considered part of the previous command and “eaten up“. Try using `\⎵` or `~`.

Comment: Thank you! Works perfect.

Comment: Not-totally-off topic: Typographically correct would be an en dash or em dash here, so `--` or `---` instead of just one `-`.